# On the number of monic polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb N$ with $c<b$.

Let $N_+(a,b,c,d)$ be the number of monic polynomials $f\in \Bbb Z[x]$of degree $d$ with non-negative coefficients such that $$f(a)=b$$ $$f(0)=c$$

What is the value of $$\sum_{d=0}^tN_+(a,b,c,d)?$$

Are there sharp estimates?

Comment: This looks like something one could examine a bit with a computer. Any special cases that you have looked at?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but note that by definition $N_+(a,b,c,d)$ is the number of ways of writing $b$ as a sum $b=\sum_{k=0}^d c_ka^k$ with non-negative $c_k$, and with  $c_0=c$ and $c_d=1$. In particular it is certainly zero unless $a|(b-c)$ and $b-c\ge a^d$, in which case $N_+(a,b,c,d):=A\big(\frac{b-c-a^d}{a}\big)$, where $A(n)$ is the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum $n=\sum_{k=0}^{d-2}x_k a^k$, with non-negative integers $x_k$, therefore corresponding to a g.f.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty A(n)x^n=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^a)(1-x^{a^2})\dots (1-x^{a^{d-2}})   }\ .$$

Comment: Is there a reference for this generating function and usage? I have not used much generating functions.

Comment: $c_k$ instead of $x_k$?

Comment: could you provide a short derivation?

Comment: yes, $x_k:=c_{k-1}$.

Comment: Short derivation: just expand each geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x^A}=1+x^A+x^{2A}+x^{3A}+x^{4A}\dots$. You can easily convince yourself that, multiplying  three (or 2, or more) geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x^A}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^B}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^C}$ you get, as a coefficient of $x^n$, the number of nonnegative integer solutions $(X,Y,Z)$ to $n=AX+BY+CZ$.

Comment: You can find quite a lot of material if you google e.g. "integer partition theory". I'm confident there should be somewhere your series too, $\prod_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{1-x^{a^k}}.$

Answer (score 2):

Really a comment on Pietro's answer: the generating function implies that the number $A(n)$ is asymptotic to a constant times $n^{d-2}$ - since the OP cares about estimates, this seems relevant to point out.

Comment: And the constant is given by Schur's theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem